# How to check for rotated objects translated points collisions?

Tags: c#, 2d, collision-detection

I've got two rectangles on WindowsForm and I would like to check if they collide. For simple non-rotated collision it looks like this:

```
Point newLocation; // upper-left corner of the object to check its collision
Size objectSize; // the object size
bool collision = false;

foreach (Object otherObject in otherObjects)
{
    if (newLocation.X >= otherObject.location.X && newLocation.X <= otherObject.location.X + otherObject.size.width)
        if (newLocation.Y >= otherObject.location.Y && newLocation.Y <= otherObject.location.Y + otherObject.size.height)
        {
            collision = true;
            break;
        }
}
```

But now I rotated both objects with:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.RotateAt(angle, newLocation);
graphics.Transform = matrix;
```

How can I check for the collisions at the rotated matrix? Can I somehow get the translated X, Y coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

I have some code to transfer points from the standard coordinate system to a specific coordinate system (but in you case, Y increases downards in screen, so some adjusts were made and commented).

Here, the double[] represents a point, where index 0 is X coordinate and index 1 is Y.
Notice the angle of the new coordinate system is measurede counterclockwise and in radians. (Multiply by Pi/180 to transform degrees to radians).

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Implemented - Returns the point coordinates related to a new coordinate system
    /// Does not change original point
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Point">Point to be returned in new coordinate system</param>
    /// <param name="NewSystemCouterClockRotation">CounterClokWise Angle of rotation of the new coordinate system compared to the current, measured in radians</param>
    /// <param name="NewSystemOrigin">Location of the new origin point in the current coordinate system</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public double[] ChangeCoordinateSystem(double[] Point, double NewSystemCouterClockRotation, double[] NewSystemOrigin)
    {

        //first adjust: fix that winform downwards increasing Y before applying the method
        Point[1] = -Point[1];
        NewSystemOrigin[1] = -NewSystemOrigin[1]

        //end of first adjust


        //original method
        double[] Displacement = new double[2] { Point[0] - NewSystemOrigin[0], Point[1] - NewSystemOrigin[1] };


        double[] Result = new double[2]
        {
            + Displacement[0] * Math.Cos(NewSystemCouterClockRotation) + Displacement[1] * Math.Sin(NewSystemCouterClockRotation), 
            - Displacement[0] * Math.Sin(NewSystemCouterClockRotation) + Displacement[1] * Math.Cos(NewSystemCouterClockRotation) 
        }; 

        //second adjust: reset Y of the result
        Result[1] = - Result[1];

        return Result;
    }
```

But, if your two objects have different angles, you should be careful, the best way to do that is to check if `all four corners of the first` of the first rectangle are not inside the other object AND if `the other object four corners` are not inside the first as well.

Some algorythm to find out if a point is inside a polygon can be found here:
[Point in polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100931/point-in-polygon)